# Colouring and renaming items with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map and I cant seem to colour the chest's name. I know you can do this:

```
give @a minecraft:chest 1 0 {display:{Name:"epic chest"}}
```

and this:

```
tellraw @a {"text":"cool text","color":"gold"}
```

So I was wondering if you could do something like

```
give @a minecraft:chest 1 0 {display:{name:"epic chest",color:"gold"}
```

but that doesn’t seem to work. I have seen this done so I know it is possible, but I don’t know how

Answer (score 4):

Item display names do not support the JSON text component. The only features that currently use the text component are `/tellraw`, `/title`, book pages, and sign text.

You will otherwise need to use the [legacy formatting codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes) via the section symbol (§). Be aware that this method is deprecated and will be removed in the future, replaced fully with the text component.

You can use a third-party NBT editor such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) to insert the section symbol.

Image example, editing the `Command` tag of a command block to include the section symbol:

[image: NBTExplorer window]

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
/give (name) 1 Chest name:&6Epic_Chest lore:&6Something
```